# What is the different between {$hello}, ${hello} & $hello when use double quotes?

Tags: php

I'm a bit confuse with

```
$hello = "hello";
echo "Say $hello";
echo "Say {$hello}";
echo "Say ${hello}";
```

and the output is same `Say hello`. When should I use `{$hello}` and `${hello}`? and why it cannot be used in single quote?

Comment: Someone has gone and [written a manual about this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex). Did you read it?

Comment: Thank you @LinusKleen. Now I know it's `curly`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$animal = 'cat';
echo "I have 14 $animals";
```

This may lead to problems, thus you will "escape" it

```
echo "I have 14 ${animal}s";
```

or

```
echo "I have 14 {$animal}s";
```

In single caused variables/expression were *never* substituted.

Answer (score 0):

Single quoted string will never expand variables in PHP. See:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

for more detail of the string formats in PHP. There are 4 in total (including nowdoc introduced in PHP 5.3). Only double quoted and heredoc string formats cause variables to be expanded.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing ,
this is a simple syntax:

```
echo "Say ${hello}";
```

and this is a curly syntax:

```
echo "Say {$hello}";
```

Why does them both output the same? Becaus in PHP you can use variable variables in every place you want. For example:

```
$var = 'somevar';
$bar = 'var';
echo $$bar; // "somevar", simple variable variable
echo ${$bar}; // "somevar", complex syntax
echo ${bar}; // "var", because {bar} treated as a string constant:
             // Notice: Use of undefined constant bar - assumed 'bar'
```

So, using variable variables syntax `${hello}` simply translated to `$hello`.